# CSS Image Tiling Border Bleedout in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, tile

Trying to build a large image viewer by tiling a series of smaller absolutely positioned image tiles together. This renders find in most browsers, where each tiled image appears perfectly lined up to the surrounding ones. However, on some browsers, most notably when viewing this on a high DPI laptop like the Macbook Pro on Google Chrome, when zooming in the page in and out several factors, there appears to be a border bleed out on some tiles. Not sure why this happens. I'm not a CSS expert, but if anyone could point out what CSS rules I'm missing to make this look flawless on all browsers, it would be greatly appreciated.

JSFiddle Link: https://jsfiddle.net/w5kfseno/

Try viewing the link in Google Chrome when zoomed out of 67%. There should not be any blue lines at all.

In case the link doesn't work, below is the HTML and CSS

```
<div class="container">
<div class="tile img"         
    style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 256px; height: 256px;"></div>
<div class="tile img"         
    style="left: 256px; top: 0px; width: 256px; height: 256px;"></div>
<div class="tile img"        
    style="left: 512px; top: 0px; width: 256px; height: 256px;"></div>
<div class="tile img"         
    style="left: 0px; top: 256px; width: 256px; height: 256px;"></div>
<div class="tile img"         
    style="left: 256px; top: 256px; width: 256px; height: 256px;"></div>
<div class="tile img"         
    style="left: 512px; top: 256px; width: 256px; height: 256px;"></div>
<div class="tile img"         
    style="left: 0px; top: 512px; width: 256px; height: 256px;"></div>
<div class="tile img"         
    style="left: 256px; top: 512px; width: 256px; height: 256px;"></div>
<div class="tile img"         
    style="left: 512px; top: 512px; width: 256px; height: 256px;"></div>
```

```
.container{
width: 768px; height:768px;position:relative;
}

.img{
background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,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');
}

.container .tile{
background-color:#33F;
display: inline-block;
margin: 0;
vertical-align: top;
position: absolute;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
pointer-events: none!important;
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
-webkit-user-drag: none;
border: none;   
border-style:none;
border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

Comment: so your problem is when you zoom in and out there are blue lines appearing at those zoom points?

Comment: I dont see any images or any absolute positioning either?

Answer (score 0):

*I don't fully understand what your asking, but - I would approach your goal (cleaner) like below:*  ;)

**[Simple JSfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g17b347d/)**. **<--**

---

```css
#container {
width: 515px;
height: 75px;
overflow: hidden;
border: 3px double #000;
white-space: nowrap;
}

#container img {display: inline-block;}

img { max-width: 100px; }
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <img src="http://cdn.sheknows.com/articles/2013/04/Puppy_2.jpg">
    <img src="http://cdn.sheknows.com/articles/2013/04/Puppy_2.jpg">
    <img src="http://cdn.sheknows.com/articles/2013/04/Puppy_2.jpg">
    <img src="http://cdn.sheknows.com/articles/2013/04/Puppy_2.jpg">
    <img src="http://cdn.sheknows.com/articles/2013/04/Puppy_2.jpg">
    <img src="http://cdn.sheknows.com/articles/2013/04/Puppy_2.jpg">
    <img src="http://cdn.sheknows.com/articles/2013/04/Puppy_2.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: I can't use images, I'd rather use divs with background images. The red is an image placeholder, simply because I couldn't find a suitable 256 px image to replace it (use your imagination instead). The problem is that I can see blue lines at various zoom levels in Chrome. This should not be happening.